# Close PDF file from WebBrowser Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, pdf

I'm having a WPF window that loads a PDF file with a WebBrowser Control.

At first glence, it works well but after a certain number of PDF was loaded, I'm getting a message from Adobe saying that the maximum number of file has been opened and that I need to close some before opening new ones.

The webbrowser control does not know by nature what content is being displayed so I don't know how to tell it to close the pdf.
I've tried clearing its cache, navigating to "About:Blank", even tried to dynamically recreating the control but so far, nothing worked.

Comment: Are the PDFs local or on the web?

Comment: They are local.

Comment: Roughly speaking how many PDFs do you need to open to get the issue (trying to replicate the problem)?

Comment: To make it simple, it looks like following : <WebBrowser Source="{Binding FileNamePath}" />. Every time the Source property changes, the controls loads that PDF into the control view but never releases the previous one. Try this 30 to 50 time in a row and Adobe will returns a message saying I need to close previous ones before opening new ones.

Comment: Try WebBrowser.Navigate(filenamepath) instead. Does that cause the same issue?

Comment: Yes, same behavior occurs. I could also say that when you look at the task manager process associated with the application, the memory keeps adding up and never releases.

Comment: I've tried loading 83 PDFs, still no errors. I'll keep trying to replicate the issue. Just curious, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: Version 11 and it's something I have no control over...Company standard. Can you see the memory adding up ?

Comment: Nope, my app doesn't significantly change in memory allocation. What are you using to loop through the PDFs? (eg. timer, for...next, loop etc.)

Comment: I have the same problem, how can we close a pdf in the webbrowser ??